# Yup: How to validate field only when it exists?

Tags: reactjs, yup, react-hook-form

Is it possible to validate a field only when it exists?

I'm going to create an application. A field(email) may / may not display on step 2, it depends on the step 1's selected option. The problem is that I can't put `email: Yup.string().Required()`, it causes that the validation run all the time even the field is not displayed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set a additional boolean key where value is default false. Change it to true when you modify the value in step 1. And then if the value is true for that key then apply the validation.

Something like this.

```
    const initialSchema= {
      name: '',
      isEmail: false, // change this when you want to add validation
      email: '',
      phone: '',
    };
    
    const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
      name: Yup.string()
        .required('Enter Name')
      isEmail: Yup.boolean(),
      email: Yup.string().when('isEmail', {
         is: true,
         then: Yup.string()
         .required('Enter Email ID'),
         otherwise: Yup.string(),
      }),
      phone: Yup.string()
        .required('Enter Mobile No'),
    });
```

Here is the [documentation reference](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedwhenkeys-string--arraystring-builder-object--value-schema-schema-schema) for same.

**Update:**

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-haze-82j4q) is the working codesandbox. I've added checkbox with `display:none;`, and added the default state values in data context.

Comment: I had tried that way before, but not work. I think this is work for same step instead of step to step. because `isEmail` is from step 1 and use it on step 2. @Nik @Dharman Do you have further solution on this stuff? Thanks.

Comment: Are your forms different for both steps? or is it just one single form split in steps?

Comment: form different for both steps

Comment: Oh ok. You can set the initialSchema based on step 1 form values. Since you know whether to show email field or not, you can modify the initialSchema for second step form and reinitialize the form based on same value. Can you provide the code snippet of your code?

Comment: Pls check out [code snippet](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-hofstadter-gj8h4?file=/src/Step2.js). I dunno how to set initial Schema base on step 1 and use it. Do you have any some example?

Comment: Please check the updated answer. I've modified the codesandbox and added working solution.

Comment: I am still getting validation message when using this with a date field, setting it to yup.date() instead of yup.string. Does one need to do something else for dates?

Comment: @jbreslow can you please add a snippet to help me understand the problem?

Comment: can you help to answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75124686/yup-validation-with-conditons

Answer (score 7):

I saw another related answer here, maybe this is a valid solution too?

https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/1114

Copying code from there:

```
const schema = yup.object({
    phone: yup.string().when('$exist', {
        is: exist => exist,
        then: yup.string().required(),
        otherwise: yup.string()
    })
})
```

Comment: Thank you! This works for me. I like this solution is more simpe.

Comment: This does not work for me.

Comment: can you help to answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75124686/yup-validation-with-conditons

Answer (score 2):

You can use Cyclic Dependency for make this.

Example:

```
const YOUR_SCHEMA_NAME = yup.object().shape({
    email: yup.string().when('email', {
        is: (exists) => !!exists,
        then: yup.string().email(),
        otherwise: yup.string(),
    }),
}, [['email', 'email']]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I modify the schema on the fly with a transform

```
  const updateUserValidator = yup.object().shape({
        email: yup.string(),
        updateBy: yup.string()
    }).transform(function (current, original) {
        this.fields.email = original?.email?.length === undefined ? yup().string().email() : yup().string().email().required()
        return current;
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late but maybe someone is going to need this answer .I've tried all the above answers and nothing worked, this the solution that i tried and it works perfectly.

In my case i had a condition based on it i display or hide the textfield, so this the solution :

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    yourFieldHere: Yup.number().when(["service"], (service, schema) => {
      return (your condition here)
        ? schema.typeError("your msg here ").required("your msg here ")
        : schema.nullable();
    }),
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to handle with manually, not with required. Just you need to keep a state of the each field. And check it if its value is present then you need to show it.
Some like this

```js
const [email, setEmail]= useState(null);

const onChange=(e)=>{
setEmail(e.target.value)
}

return (


<input type="text" onChange={onChnage}/>
)
```

And pass this email to your parent where you checking for validation. If there is any thin in **email** then show it do other validation. Or if it is empty or Null then don't show it.

Thanks