# Is it possible in yup js to have conditional validation on self

Tags: reactjs, typescript, yup

Is it possible to do self validation if and only if self has value?

```
password: yup.string().default("").when("password", {
  is: '' || null,
  then: yup.string().notRequired(),
  otherwise: yup.string().matches(
    /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,})/,
    "Must Contain 8 or more characters: One Uppercase, One Lowercase, One Number and One Special Case Character"
  )
}),
```

Because this seems to have circular dependency error.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: maybe this could hep https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/1114 ?

Comment: or someone here suggests to create a state variable as an alternative https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65613573/yup-how-to-validate-field-only-when-it-exists

Comment: @ppichier, the 2nd one is not working with the "matches: function though, the first one works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits to @ppichier, I'm also including a confirm password field

```
const validation = yup.object().shape({
password: yup.string().default("").when("password", {
    is: (exist: boolean) => exist,
    then: yup.string().required()
      .matches(
        /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,})/,
        "Must Contain 8 or more characters: One Uppercase, One Lowercase, One Number and One Special Case Character"
      ),
    otherwise: yup.string().notRequired()
}),

confirmPassword: yup.string().default("")
  .when("password", {
    is: '' || null,
    then: yup.string().notRequired(),
    otherwise: yup.string().oneOf([yup.ref('password'), null], 'Passwords must match.')

  }}, [['password', 'password']]);
```