# How to conditionally render Yup validation in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yup

I got this simple example which was highly related to my doubt, so I am using this as my example. So here in the link we can see there is a simple Yup validation schema. So when we type in something inside email field, the console log inside the email validation is getting printed which is obviously fine. But even when we type something inside the name field also the console is getting printed.

**Validation Schema**

```
const schema = yup.object({
  name: yup.string().required(),
  email: yup.string().test('is-jimmy', '${path} is not Jimmy', function (value) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      console.log('firing async validation')
      setTimeout(() => res(value !== "foo@bar.com"))
    }) 
  })

})
```

**Example** - https://stackblitz.com/edit/yup-async-validation-test?file=index.js

Please suggest me a solution to get rid of this issue, so that the console have to print only when I type inside the email field.

**Alternate solution ?** -
Is there any method to add more than 1 validation schemas in Formik to avoid this issue ?

```
 // like this
<Formik validationSchema = [userValidationSchema,emailSchema] />
```

Comment: There are conditional usage over field validations with `when` in `Yup` schema. As well as `Yup.lazy`. You can look into those.

Answer (score 0):

This is how yup work, on some of your field change, you pass a new object for a validation and yup doesn't know which field was actually changed recently, so validation run for a whole object.

In case if you will split validation schema into separate validation for each field, you would be able to configure it to work like you expect.

Comment: Is it possible to split validation and use multiple validation schema in Formik?

Comment: As a suggestion you can have two validations, in first you will send only recently changed field. This validation will check fields only if exists (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65613573/yup-how-to-validate-field-only-when-it-exists). And the second one validation is submit validation that check for required fields. 

But maybe a better solution for your case will be validating as normal, and run backend validation only on submit. That way it would be fired so many times

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by initializing a state in the start i.e

```
const [check,setCheck]=useState();
```

Then in your handle change function set the state:

```
 handleChange = (field) => (e) => {
    this.setState({ [field]: e.target.value});
    setCheck(field) //setting the state
    schema.isValid(this.state);
  };
```

Finally add a check in your yup schema:

```
const schema = yup.object({
  name: yup.string().required(),
  email: yup
    .string()
    .test('is-jimmy', '${path} is not Jimmy', function (value) {
      return new Promise((res, rej) => {
       //condition for not logging in case of name
        if(check!= "name") {
        console.log('firing async validation');
        }
        setTimeout(() => res(value !== 'foo@bar.com'));
      });
    }),
});
```